# ¿Hay alguna forma que createTempFile no crea estos números aleatorios despues del prefix?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

```
private fun createFilePerfil(): File {
    return File.createTempFile("perfil", ".png", externalCacheDir)
}
```

//resultado perfil4307939079430928921.png

Comment: al ser un archivo temporal el nombre random es para evitar colisiones, si el archivo va a ser usado en otro contexto o lugar una vez que terminas de manipularlo ( resize, crop, filter, etc) lo grabas con nombre final en su ubicación final via copy o move